# -F Curl option on PHP

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to run CURL command in PHP to upload image to an API
the code mentioned in the doc was:

`curl -u 15:tokenkeyiskmzwa8awaa https://api.bukalapak.com/v2/images.json -F file=@product-image.png -X POST`

Have tried using mac terminal running this curl command (with proper username and password) and successfully got the result as it is uploading, however was not successfully doing it on PHP.
My php code is :

```
<?php

$data = array('file'=> '@'.$imagePath ); 

// this is an absolute path, give something like D://folder/path/on/my/webserver/image.jpg

$user = '1234567';

$pass = '123456';

$ch = curl_init();

$curl_options[CURLOPT_URL]  = 'https://api.bukalapak.com/v2/images.json';

$curl_options[CURLOPT_CAINFO] = storage_path('app/cacert.pem');

$curl_options[CURLOPT_HEADER] = "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

$curl_options[CURLOPT_POST] = 1;

$curl_options[CURLOPT_USERPWD] = $user.':'.$pass;

$curl_options[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS] = http_build_query($data);

curl_setopt_array($ch, $curl_options);

$content = curl_exec($->ch);`
```

Curl version :  7.47.1
PHP version : 5.6.21
any feedback is very appreciated.

Comment: Are there any errormessages? How and where exactly does the code fail?

Comment: The error message was 500 Forbidden, and I think it was because I use `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` that's coverted equivalent to -d on curl. But problem solved as pointed by @swapgs by using `curl_file_create` that implement -F on curl function. Thanks for reply though.

Comment: HTTP status code 500 mean "Internal Server Error", not "Forbidden" ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did not posted the complete script: `$curl_options` is undefined, `storage_path` is related to Laravel but there is no import, etc.
Something like the following script should work as you expect (I didn't tested it since I don't have an account on this service):

```
<?php

$imagePath = 'path/to/your/image.ext';
$user = 'youruser';
$pass = 'yourpass';

$file = curl_file_create($imagePath);
$body = ['file' => $file];
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.bukalapak.com/v2/images.json');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $user.':'.$pass);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, 'path/to/cacert.pem');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, yes I'm sorry for not posting the full script but I assure you there isn't any error on PHP script and curl working fine. However I got 500 server error from the server if I run the PHP script while if I'm using the curl command from mac terminal it works fine. I thinks the CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS was translated to -d which is not the server want. The server want -F option. So any idea how to implement -F option to curl function in PHP ?

Comment: The line calling `curl_file_create()` is the equivalent of the `-F` parameter.

Comment: I edited my answer to fix the POST parameter name (`s/file_contents/file/`).

Comment: Hey Thanks man!
That's work like a magic. Really helps me a lot. Have spent many hours trying to implement this -F with no lucks. 
Thanks again ! God Bless You ! :)

Comment: Actually, `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` is the equivalent to `-F` parameter. `curl_file_create` is the equivalent to `@somefile.ext`.